# How to steam camera video to a steaming server (like vimeo, youtube, other)

Tags: cordova

I want to create an application using cordova. One user will broadcast his/her camera video and many people will watch it (hundreds if not thousands).

I think the only solution for this is using a streaming server (because webrtc works only peer to peer). But I don't know how to send video stream to a server. Using cordova-plugin-camera-stream I can reach video stream. But that's it.

What do you suggest?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC works perfectly fine if the other end of the connection is a server and not a browser. See [this blog post](https://bloggeek.me/media-server-for-webrtc-broadcast/) for a detailed explanation of the architecture involved.